# How to access to the DOM element that fired the function?

Tags: jquery, function, events, dom

So I have my jQuery event created when the DOM is ready such as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('A#myId').bind('click', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        console.log($(this));
    });
});
```

I therefore access to the DOM-element that fired the event with `e` and `$(this)` quite easily.

The problem I have is when I want to have my script in a function such as

```
function myFunction()
{
    console.log();
}
```

and the firing script such as

```
<a id="myId" onclick="myFunction()">My link</a>
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('A#myId').bind('click', function(e) {
        myFunction()
    });
});
```

How can I access to the DOM-element that fired the event with that structure ?

Also, can you put a function in the part when DOM is ready ? Such as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function myFunction()
    {

    }
});
```

Many thanks in advance (I am relatively new to jQuery and I'm lacking some basis) and sorry if such a topic has already been answered, my previous research was unsuccessful (due to poor quality keywords).

Comment: pass `this` inside the onlick attribute as a parameter to the function. or better yet, **don't use onclick attributes**

Comment: Thanks for your answer advising me not to use onClick attributes, I won't anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<a id="myId" onclick="myFunction(this, event)">My link</a>
function myFunction(element, event)
{
    console.log(element + event);
}
```

Or

```
$('A#myId').bind('click', function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);   
        Call Your Method(e) // event will be defined
});
```

Where

`this` will be you html object, and event is for getting event be the event

You can check it using `event.keyCode` and may other manipulations as per requirements

Comment: Thanks for answering! This is what I have tried just after asking the question. I also can do `$('A#myId').bind('click', myFunction);` and the `e` will be passed into the function. Thanks again. Also, what about declaring a function in the DOM-ready section?

Answer (score 0):

I have just given a try by doing this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('A#myId').bind('click', function(e) {
        myFunction(e)
    });
});
```

and this

```
function myFunction(e)
{
    console.log(e);
}
```

and it seems to work.

Is it the only way of doing it?

Comment: Definitely isn't the *"only"* way of doing it, but it'l work. you could have simply done `$('#myId').bind('click',myFunction)`

Comment: Thanks! It seems indeed to work when I retrieve it by doing `myFunction(e) { console.log(e); }`.